# Is it possible to protect google spreadsheet data using the web api?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to programmatically create google spreadsheets that have some columns marked as 'read-only'. Using the web browser client this is straight forward, but I have not found any documentation on how to do this via the API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this by relying on the Drive API exclusively. The good thing is, there is a Google Sheets API. This will allow you to access your Sheet file and edit its content. More information can be found on this resource: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/.

Comment: Thanks @Rivero - I looked through the docs at the link you provided, but I can't find any mention of protecting certain fields.